# en_core_web_md installation fails

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I've installed spaCy (version 2.3.0) and now I'm trying to install one of the models, namely `en_core_web_md`. I'm running the command from their website, which is `python -m spacy download en_core_web_md`. When I run the command, I get this error: `ValueError: cymem.cymem.Pool has the wrong size, try recompiling. Expected 64, got 48`

Here's the full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\achandra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\runpy.py", line 185, in _run_module_as_main
    mod_name, mod_spec, code = _get_module_details(mod_name, _Error)
  File "C:\Users\achandra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\runpy.py", line 144, in _get_module_details
    return _get_module_details(pkg_main_name, error)
  File "C:\Users\achandra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\runpy.py", line 111, in _get_module_details
    __import__(pkg_name)
  File "C:\Users\achandra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\spacy\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from thinc.neural.util import prefer_gpu, require_gpu
  File "C:\Users\achandra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\thinc\neural\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from ._classes.model import Model  # noqa: F401
  File "C:\Users\achandra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\thinc\neural\_classes\model.py", line 11, in <module>
    from ..train import Trainer
  File "C:\Users\achandra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\thinc\neural\train.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .optimizers import Adam, linear_decay
  File "optimizers.pyx", line 14, in init thinc.neural.optimizers
  File "ops.pyx", line 1, in init thinc.neural.ops
  File "cymem.pxd", line 1, in init preshed.maps
ValueError: cymem.cymem.Pool has the wrong size, try recompiling. Expected 64, got 48
```

How do I fix this? For reference, I am using python 3.8.3

Comment: Can you try using an earlier version of spaCy? `pip install spacy==2.2.4`

Comment: @raqib when I tried that I got this error: `ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1108)`

Comment: can you also downgrade python to 3.8?

Comment: Have you tried installing (the latest) spaCy from scratch in a clean virtual environment?